# url routing not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to use routing in CodeIgniter i was not able to get i want to pass test controller here's the code
I want the url like this localhost/code/test  ibut i am getting object not found

```
routes.php

    $route['test'] = "test/blog"; 

    test.php controller

    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Test extends CI_Controller {

        /**
         * Index Page for this controller.
         *
         * Maps to the following URL
         *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
         *  - or -  
         *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
         *  - or -
         * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
         * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
         *
         * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
         * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
         * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        }

        public function blog()
        {

         echo "hi";
        }
    }

    /* End of file welcome.php */
    /* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is you need to prepare a view page within `views` folder like `blog.php` and what you need to do is you need to pass data within it and have to call view part within your controller like as

`test.php`

```
public function blog()
{
    $data['my_post'] = "Hello Its my first blog"; //some sort of operations or else likewise
    $this->load->view('blog',$data);
}
```

within `blog.php`

```
<h1><?php echo $my_post;?></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have not set default controller in route then first of all set it after that set specific routing like this

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Test";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['test'] = 'test/blog';
$route['test/(:any)'] = 'test/blog/$1';
```

Answer (score 0):

First Of all make Default controller to your file. From Route.php